# How does the star * behave in Python's regex vs. glob pattern search?

Tags: python, regex, glob

I am trying to understand how `glob` works, also how is the star `*` related to `glob` and how it works vs. how it works in regex?

For example, I know `glob.glob("C:\Users\Me\MyFolder\*.txt")` would match and return any files with the extension `.txt` in the given path but how would that compare to finding text files using Regex? Is one better in performance than the other? higher speed or less computation memory?

Comment: ...anyhow -- for a question to be on-topic, it needs to be narrow and specific; thus, asking about not just a character, but a specific syntactical use. And almost certainly, there will already be Q&A entries in our database covering any specific usage you might want to ask about.

Comment: Hey there! I would recommend doing some python research for [3.7.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) or for [2.7.16](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: To be fair, the Python documentation doesn't explain the glob patterns, only "according to the rules used by the Unix shell".

Comment: ... which will lead to e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html when searched for.

Comment: Sure; *if* that's what the OP wants to know, https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern may be pertinent, with the understanding that no extensions are covered. However, the body of the question doesn't in any way back up that interpretation; it's only the title that mentions globs at all.

Comment: Well, given "I am trying to understand how glob works" I think we can assume that the question is about glob patterns, not `*args`.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 for your link. It was helpful!

Comment: @JROS, that edit definitely brings the body in line with the title; I'd want to see the OP approve it as what they meant to ask before accepting an edit that speaks so loudly to a question's intent (and reopening the question, as the flagged duplicates would clearly no longer be suitable).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy First, I think I made it very clear in the question that I am new to python, so apologies if my question caused so much inconvenience to you. However, thanks for your help! Second, when I was learning using the function '''glob''' in python, I tried to link it a little bit to the command '''find''' in Ubuntu such that it I can use '''find''' to look for files either with certain names or certain file extentions. Therefore, I just wanted to understand it further along with these symbols related to scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about a '*' in the pattern, then, typically `*` just means "match any number of characters" or better "match 0 or more characters", so if we assume we have files in a directory: `apple  cherry  custard  green_apple` then you can get lists of files for example:

```
import glob

print("glob.glob('a*') -> {}".format(glob.glob('a*'))) # match starting with 'a'

print("glob.glob('*a*') -> {}".format(glob.glob('*a*'))) # match anything that contains an 'a'

print("glob.glob('apple*') -> {}".format(glob.glob('apple*'))) # match if starts with 'apple'

print("glob.glob('*apple*') -> {}".format(glob.glob('*apple*'))) # match if 'apple' is in the filename
```

This would return

```
glob.glob('a*') -> ['apple']
glob.glob('*a*') -> ['apple', 'custard', 'green_apple']
glob.glob('apple*') -> ['apple']
glob.glob('*apple*') -> ['apple', 'green_apple']
```

This is a very simplistic view of what you can do with [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html).